Combine two tables doing row count based on hour value in timestamp
I've got two tables:
utilities:



id
timestamp
action




901
2024-08-11 09:59:25.000
on power


902
2024-08-11 09:59:35.000
on water


903
2024-08-11 09:59:55.000
off power


904
2024-08-11 10:01:25.000
on gas


905
2024-08-11 10:02:35.000
off water


906
2024-08-11 10:11:18.000
off power


907
2024-08-11 10:31:28.000
off gas


908
2024-08-11 11:15:37.000
on power



items:



id
timestamp
action




906
2024-08-11 09:59:45.000
on lights


907
2024-08-11 09:59:58.000
off lights


908
2024-08-11 10:15:34.000
on tap


909
2024-08-11 10:18:25.000
on heating


910
2024-08-11 10:21:44.000
off heating


911
2024-08-11 11:02:35.000
off tap


912
2024-08-11 12:01:08.000
open door


913
2024-08-11 12:11:28.000
closer door



I'm trying to combine them, without the ids clashing (generate a new id?) and then want to do a date_trunc('hour', timestamp) as time, COUNT(*) as metric to work out how many actions are happening in the table per hour, so the end result would be:



time
metric




2024-08-11 09:00:00.000
5


2024-08-11 10:00:00.000
7


2024-08-11 11:00:00.000
2


2024-08-11 12:00:00.000
2



I tried this query, but it complains about:

Utilities.timestamp must appear in the GROUP BY ...

WITH one AS (
  SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour', timestamp) as timeOne, 
  COUNT(*) as utilities_count
  FROM Utilities
  ORDER BY timeOne
),
two AS (
  SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour', timestamp) as timeTwo, 
  COUNT(*) as item_count
  FROM Items
  ORDER BY timeTwo
)
SELECT 
  SUM(utilities_count, item_count) as metric,
  timeOne as time
FROM one, two
ORDER BY 1;

Any idea how to get the data combined and counted with the correct hourly binning?

Simply:
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp) AS time, count(*) AS metric
FROM  (
   SELECT timestamp FROM utilities
   UNION ALL
   SELECT timestamp FROM items
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;

Clashing IDs are not relevant to this query. Simply append rows from both tables with UNION ALL (not just UNION!), use date_trunc() and aggregate.
I removed a more complex query that would only make sense with (unlikely) expression indexes on underlying tables.

This answer would be better with an explanation.

I like that the explanation is as short and succinct as the code it proposes. I couldn't persuade the now removed query to use the index, but I ended up coming up with one that does - it's not a pleasant sight. For a task this simple, I'd favor the approach proposed here.

This approach works well - I'm yet to see how the speed affects it as the (non-anonymous) version if being used in grafana

count is an aggregate function which combines the values of multiple rows together. You have to tell Postgres how to group rows with a group by clause. You want to group by hour, so GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', timestamp) or GROUP BY 1.
Also, you do not want to do a cross join which will result in each row in one being joined with every row in two. Instead you can union both tables together and then group, but this can't take advantage of indexes. Instead, count both tables (which can use an index), then union and group and sum the counts together (only a handful of rows).
WITH hours AS (
  SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour', recorded_at) as "hour", 
  COUNT(*) as "count"
  FROM utilities
  GROUP BY 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour', recorded_at) as "hour", 
  COUNT(*) as "count"
  FROM items
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT 
  "hour",
  SUM("count") as "count"
FROM hours
GROUP BY "hour"
ORDER BY "hour";

Demonstration.
Other notes...

Ordering the subqueries will just slow things down. Only the final query needs to be ordered.
Avoid naming columns using keywords like timestamp. They risk errors and don't have a lot of descriptive power. Follow the thing_at for timestamps and thing_on for dates.
There are a lot of SQL keywords and they're hard to avoid, quote them if you use them to avoid ambiguity and bizarre errors.


If you like negligible performance gains, you can overcomplicate things with the overkill below. It results in an emulated index skip scan:
with recursive cte as (
  (select date_trunc('hour',recorded_at) as t,count(*)
  from utilities
  group by 1 order by 1 limit 1)
  union all
  select lat.t,lat.count
  from cte cross join lateral
  ( select date_trunc('hour',recorded_at) as t,count(*)
    from utilities
    where date_trunc('hour',recorded_at)>cte.t
    group by 1 order by 1 limit 1) lat )
,cte2 as (
  (select date_trunc('hour',recorded_at) as t,count(*)
  from items
  group by 1 order by 1 limit 1)
  union all
  select lat.t,lat.count
  from cte cross join lateral
  ( select date_trunc('hour',recorded_at) as t,count(*)
    from items
    where date_trunc('hour',recorded_at)>cte.t
    group by 1 order by 1 limit 1) lat )
select t,coalesce(cte.count,0)+coalesce(cte2.count,0) as count
from cte full join cte2 using (t);

If you set up 2 tables, populate them with 100k random timestamps each, eqip both with a covering index on expression:
select setseed(.42);

create table utilities(recorded_at)as 
select (now()-random()*'3 months'::interval)::timestamp
from generate_series(1,1e5);

create table items(recorded_at)as 
select (now()-random()*'3 months'::interval)::timestamp
from generate_series(1,1e5);

create index utilities_idx on utilities(date_trunc('hour',recorded_at) asc)
  include(recorded_at)--necessary to upgrade index scan to index-only scan
  with(fillfactor=100);
create index items_idx on items(date_trunc('hour',recorded_at) asc)
  include(recorded_at)
  with(fillfactor=100);

Then make sure they are freshly analysed (and actually even clustered to help out seq scans), you'll find how little this much code and effort contributes to performance:
explain plans and performance tests at db<>fiddle



variant
mode
avg
min
max
stddev




joined_index_skip_scans_zegarek
00:00:00.0693
00:00:00.082845
00:00:00.0693
00:00:00.280274
00:00:00.031557


grouped_union_of_ungrouped_erwin
00:00:00.084824
00:00:00.100407
00:00:00.084824
00:00:00.185166
00:00:00.020863


grouped_union_of_groups_schwern
00:00:00.086139
00:00:00.100492
00:00:00.086139
00:00:00.187825
00:00:00.021184


grouped_union_of_groups_erwin
00:00:00.087176
00:00:00.106341
00:00:00.087176
00:00:00.312548
00:00:00.038265



It does look like 30%, but that's 30% of very little already - and it's a bit of a pain to get there.
An interesting observation is that not only is the index strictly necessary for this to work, it also has to be additionally weighed down to include the raw timestamp as payload on top of the date_trunc() expression just to enable an index-only scan, even though the query never uses the raw timestamp, making it feel like it's just an expensive way to parley with the planner.
Meanwhile, the seq-scanning queries don't really need the index at all.

If you spread the 100k rows over 2 years instead of 3 months to get ~ 5 rows per hour like in the Q then the emulated index skip scan drowns in overhead and is slower than the rest. OTOH, if you add more columns to get a realistic row width, you get index-only usage for vacuumed tables for all queries, just because the index is so much smaller. Basically a seqscan over the index. Either way, +1 for making the expression index work. It does have its use for many rows per group because it scales better in that direction.
